# Index was out of range error in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

I add all row `CheckBox` in my `Gridview` helping with this [`article`](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs).

Here is my `Calculate Button` code;

```
protected void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool atLeastOneRowDeleted = false; 

        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
        { 
            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ProductSelector"); 
            if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
            { 
                atLeastOneRowDeleted = true; 
                int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); 
                Response.Write(string.Format( "This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", productID));
            }
        }

    }
```

But when i do that, getting strange error like this;

[image]

How can i solve this problem?

Best Regards, Soner

Comment: Did you look at the DataKeys collection with the debugger?

Comment: @Thomas Are CheckBox is should be cause getting this error?

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve with the code above?

Comment: @gbs I just wanna write which row selected in Gridview with this code. Response.Write(string.Format( "This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", productID));

Comment: Can you update your question with your GV markup and DataSource details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have DataKeys defined in your GridView definition

```
  <asp:gridview id="GridView2" 
        datakeynames="productID"
        ...
        ...>
    enter code here

   </asp:gridview>
```

Also try adding a check for DataRow like this

```
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows) 
    {
      if(row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      { 
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ProductSelector"); 
        if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
        { 
            atLeastOneRowDeleted = true; 
            int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value); 
            Response.Write(string.Format( "This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", productID));
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: @StackOwerflowException Sorry but your code getting this error. http://i.imgur.com/blGqw.png

Comment: @Soner check out my edit! Can you post your markup for Gridview ?

Comment: But i don't have a productID column. This is just a for CheckBoxes column. So when i write this <asp:gridview id="GridView2" datakeynames="productID"... i getting an error DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'productID'.

Comment: try `MUS_K_ISIM` for datakeysnames instead of productID

Comment: I just two column "MUS_K_ISIM" and CheckBoxes column. http://i.imgur.com/ArKi9.png

Comment: I tried MUS_K_ISIM for datakeynames but when i click calculate button i getting this error http://i.imgur.com/gDNAF.png

Comment: what are you trying to calculate ?

Comment: I just want to calculate "Which i selected in Gridview column's total price in another label" "Total Price" is another column. Just like SubTotal.

Answer (score 2):

It could be related to the way youre populating your gridview, or the way youre setting your GridView to store the DataKeys, could you post both codes, where you set up your GridView component on your .aspx page (the html code) and where you populate it?

EDIT:

I have tried your example, and the only diferrence is that I aquire a datasource from a List intead of a DataSource control, is running perfectly here, and I Ctrl+c/Ctrl+v your code, so take a look;

public class MyClass
        {
            public int productId { get; set; }
            public string MUS_K_ISIM { get; set; }
        }

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<MyClass> ChechkBoxDataSource = new List<MyClass>();
            ChechkBoxDataSource.Add(new MyClass() { productId = 1, MUS_K_ISIM = "Stack" });
            ChechkBoxDataSource.Add(new MyClass() { productId = 2, MUS_K_ISIM = "Overflow" });
            ChechkBoxDataSource.Add(new MyClass() { productId = 3, MUS_K_ISIM = "Example" });

            GridView1.DataSource = ChechkBoxDataSource;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("ProductSelector");
                if (cb != null && cb.Checked)
                {
                    int productID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
                    Response.Write(string.Format("This would have deleted ProductID {0}<br />", productID));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here is my gridview code. <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ChechkBoxDataSource" 
        PageSize="5"  datakeynames="productID">
        
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="MUS_K_ISIM" HeaderText="MUS_K_ISIM" 
                SortExpression="MUS_K_ISIM"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:templatefield>
        <itemtemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ProductSelector" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
        </itemtemplate>

        </asp:templatefield>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Comment: @Soner for this aproach to work, you should have a property containing your productId, just like the example above, where I define an int prop to represent it at MyClass. Otherwise, you should create it or find another field in order to unique identify your object.